# How to rasterize a pandas dataframe with many points per pixel?

Tags: python, rasterizing, rasterio

I am using rasterio to convert a geopandas dataframe of points to a geotif raster.
For that I am using this python code:

```
with rasterio.open("somepath/rasterized.tif", 'w+', **meta) as out:
    out.nodata = 0
    out_arr = out.read(1)

    # this is where we create a generator of geom, value pairs to use in rasterizing
    shapes = ((geom, value * 2) for geom, value in zip(gdf.geometry, gdf["PositionConfidence"]))

    burned = features.rasterize(shapes=shapes, fill=0, out=out_arr, transform=out.transform)
    out.write_band(1, burned)
    out.write_band(2, burned)
    out.write_band(3, burned)

    out_arr1 = out.read(1)
```

The code not only writes a fixed value to the raster but a value based on the point to be converted.

The problem is that there are many points per raster pixel. Using above approach only a single points value is burned to the pixel.
What I am looking for is having the average of all points values per pixel burned to the given pixel.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found some idea to do it:

First we sort all the points by pixel into a dictionary. Then we calculate the value that we need, in this case average of some value, for all points in that pixel. Now we assign this value to a new point with the coordinates of the pixel and use that instead of the old points.